# can not find bug in the code vector usage

Tags: c++, string, debugging, vector

I can't find bug in this code

In function `BinaryCode::decode(std::string)':

```
undefined reference to `BinaryCode::m_vecStr'
undefined reference to `BinaryCode::m_vecStr'
undefined reference to `BinaryCode::m_vecStr'
undefined reference to `BinaryCode::m_vecStr'
undefined reference to `BinaryCode::m_vecStr'
more undefined references to `BinaryCode::m_vecStr' follow
```

http://codepad.org/PtZkGx6W

output is in above site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class BinaryCode{
public:
BinaryCode(void);
~BinaryCode(void);
static vector<string> m_vecStr;

vector<string> decode(string message);

};

BinaryCode::BinaryCode(void){
}
BinaryCode::~BinaryCode(void){
}

vector<string> BinaryCode::decode(string message){
m_vecStr.clear();
char szNone[]={"NONE"};
m_vecStr.push_back(szNone);
m_vecStr.push_back(message);
return m_vecStr;
}

int main(){
BinaryCode bc;
  //cout<<bc.decode("12310122");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the static member outside of the class declaration. Try adding this after the class declaration:

```
vector<string> BinaryCode::m_vecStr;
```

If you're declaring your class in a distinct file, make sure you define the static members in the implementation file (generally `.cpp`), not in the header file (`.h`).

Comment: when i uncomment //cout<<bc.decode("12310122"); then also i get lots of error

Comment: That's because you're trying to print an entire `std::vector<std::string>`. You should print each of its elements instead. E.g.: `vector<string> result = bc.decode("12310122"); cout << result[0] << endl`.

Comment: why vector<string> &result=bc.decode("dssdf") i have done it without '&' and its working and with '&' its not working

Comment: There's no `&` there. I also recommend you to read a [good C++ introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug it is a linker error which tells you that linker cannot find definition for `m_vecStr`.

You need to define a static variable, in your code you just declared it but forgot to define it.
Add the following definition:

```
vector<string> BinaryCode::m_vecStr;
```

only once in your source file.

Comment: when i uncomment //cout<<bc.decode("12310122"); then also i get lots of error